# Excel VBA : How can I avoid automatic code generation when I click worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner of Excel VBA.

When I write code on VBA editer, whenever I click worksheet or do something(something like changing position or delete cells), corresponding codes are automatically generated on my VBA editer.

For example, when I click E5 cell by mouse, `Range("E5").Select` is automatically generated, and then I delete the code, always.

Would it be possible to block this automatic code generation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It only does this whilst recoding a macro so *Developer tab* => *Stop Recording* ?

Comment: Stop the macro recorder. You have it running if it is duplicating the manual actions you are performing.

Comment: Very easy~ Thank you all~